# Change windowStyle of Prism Dialogwindow

Tags: prism

How can I change the window style dynamically via Trigger?
Like:

```
<Style TargetType="UserControl">

    <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStyle" Value="{DynamicResource  DefaultDialogStyleTheme}"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>

        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding SecondOne, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Value="true">                    
            <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DialogStyleTheme}"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register your own `IDialogWindow` implementation that has all the styles you desire.

The library's implementation's code's [here (xaml)](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogWindow.xaml) and [there (code-behind)](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogWindow.xaml.cs) as a reference.

Comment: Hello,I already know the IDialogWindow. But i want to switch between normal Windows window and our curstom window via Style Trigger.

Comment: Sure, why not? Copy the existing implementation, add whatever style and triggers you want, and register that as `IDialogWindow` to override the default.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help :), But for example before we switched to new Prism, we've used a PopupWindowAction to raise a default window or a custom window:

```
  var wrapperWindow = GetWindow(args.Context);                                                                
  wrapperWindow.ShowDialog();
```

GetWindow returns a Window or CustomWindowObject.

That's the custom window style:

```
   <Style x:Key="DialogStyleTheme" TargetType="implementation:CustomDialogWindow">
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanMinimize" />
    <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="implementation:CustomDialogWindow">
                <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="White" Background="DimGray"
                        x:Name="MainBorder">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MoveGrid">
                            <Image x:Name="Image">
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                                        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="UniformToFill" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SmallTitle}" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TouchHeadTextBlock}" TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SmallTitle}" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ContentPresenter" ClipToBounds="True" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And I'm setting the WindowStyle in my UserControl and I want to change this style via trigger....

```
 prism:Dialog.WindowStyle="{DynamicResource DialogStyleTheme}"
```

Initialization:

```
    containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<ItemSelectionDialogView, ItemSelectionDialogViewModel>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<CustomDialogWindow>();
```